# Text Rotator Shows Whole List for a Split Second, then starts working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, caching, css-animations

I have a text rotator for a hero, and its functioning properly, but when I clear my cache and load the page, all the words that are supposed to rotate, show for a tiny second and then the rotator starts working. Im not sure how to prevent that. I created a fiddle, and the fiddle does not show the entire list, but the dev site I am working on does. Im thinking it might a caching plugin...that is loading deferred, but Im not sure how to configure this to work seamlessly.

```
 $(".rotate").rotator();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/EdgarAlexPoe/mhjrdy0n/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the particular library, but what you need could be as simple as adding

```
.rotate-arena li {
  display: none;
}
```

to the CSS. Seemed to work OK when I added it to your JSFIDDLE.

As for why it shows on the dev site and not the snippet, could be because the dev site has to load x, y, and z elements and scripts before it gets to the JS, while the snippet gets right to the point.

Comment: Right. I use WP rocket to combine and minify everything js/css. I turned it off, but it was little loading wonky. I will try to hide the li and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that was the simple solution. I thought I had hid the elements, but in SASS I had the child elements nested under an h3. Doh! thanks for your help @CK MacLeod

Comment: My pleasure - you're welcome